# Hibernate - Incomprehensible Warning

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have built a standalone java application (batch) that make use of Hibernate through JPA 2.
It runs fine but I constantly see this warning in the logs.

I have googled and read the source code directly with no luck.

```
WARN    org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory  TypeFactory.java:69     Scoping types to session factory org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@f876ce2 after already scoped org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@3fd7165
```

I wonder what does it mean ?

Comment: Are you defining more than a single factory that uses the same types?

Comment: Actually, I add dynamically new entities to the Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is when you set the session factory twice (the session factory has already been set). Set logging to trace and look for where it says 'Scoping types to session factory', at some point you then set it again, it appears it won't cause a problem though but the API looks like that in an ideal scenario you should only ever set the factory once.

Comment: Actually, I was creating a configuration object and reusing it continously by adding new entities to it. Creating a new configuration each time I add a new entity solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the sources:

```
public final class TypeFactory implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( TypeFactory.class );

    private final TypeScopeImpl typeScope = new TypeScopeImpl();

    public static interface TypeScope extends Serializable {
        public SessionFactoryImplementor resolveFactory();
    }

    private static class TypeScopeImpl implements TypeFactory.TypeScope {
        private SessionFactoryImplementor factory;

        public void injectSessionFactory(SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
            if ( this.factory != null ) {
                log.warn( "Scoping types to session factory {} after already scoped {}", this.factory, factory );
            }
            else {
                log.trace( "Scoping types to session factory {}", factory );
            }
            this.factory = factory;
        }
```

...

Comment: Well what scoping is ? Is this an error to scope type with different factories ?

Comment: I don't know, I thought the sources may clarify the "problem" to you!